# GridBagLayout Don't make components "jump" after add

Tags: java, swing, alignment, gridbaglayout

I want to use GridBagLayout for a layout that has <= 3 columns, and a variable amount of rows(If anyone knows another layout that can do this easily, please tell me), everytime I press the "add" button a square will be added at the first location that is available. Like so:

```
|x x x|
|x x x|
|x o  |
```

The x's are squares, and when I press add a new square should be added where the o is now.
I managed to "kind of make it work" like so:

```
public void addSquare(Square square) {
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.gridx = nrOfSquares % 3;
    c.gridy = (int) (nrOfSquares / 3);
    c.weighty = 1;
    c.weightx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    this.container.add(square, c);
    this.container.revalidate();
    ++nrOfSquares;
}
```

the problem is that the second square I add is added like this:

```
|x  x  |
```

please note that there is an extra space between the first square and the second one. I have the same problem when an extra row is added.

Now how do I fix my code so that the squares don't "jump" and are added like in the first example I gave?

EDIT: as requested, a better example after I converted it to a regular GridLayout:

```
public class Square extends JPanel {
   public Square() {
       super();     
       Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(200, 200);
       this.setSize(SIZE);
       this.setPreferredSize(SIZE);
       this.setMinimumSize(SIZE);
       this.setMaximumSize(SIZE);

       this.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

       this.setVisible(true);
   }
}

public class SquareContainer extends JPanel {
    protected JPanel realContainer;

    public SquareContainer(int width, int height) {
        super();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.realContainer = new JPanel();
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 3);
        layout.setHgap(10);
        layout.setVgap(10);
        this.realContainer.setLayout(layout);
        this.realContainer.setBackground(this.getBackground());
        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(this.realContainer);
        scroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(20);
        this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void addSquare(Square square) {
        this.realContainer.add(square);
        this.realContainer.revalidate();
    }
}
```

And I just add that to a JFrame:

```
public class TheGreatFrame extends JFrame {
    public TheGreatFrame() {
        super();
        this.setSize(800, 800);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setResizable(false);

        this.add(new SquareContainer(750, 660), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply a `GridLayout(0, 3)` (3 columns, variable number of rows)?

Comment: Ok, so that does work without problems?

Comment: It can, depending on what you want it to do. :)

Comment: Works indeed, but now the first couple of squares are stretched vertically to fit.

Comment: To get a better idea of how it's not working, create a small compilable runnable example similar to what I've done, an [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Did something like that now :)

Answer (score 4):

A small example program of using GridLayout:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridLayoutEg {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3)); 

      JButton addBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Button") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            centerPanel.add(new JButton("X"));
            centerPanel.revalidate();
            centerPanel.repaint();  

            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(centerPanel).pack();
         }
      });
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(addBtn);

      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      mainPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      mainPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridLayoutEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 because this helped me quite a bit, only problem I still have now is that my squares are stretched vertically until I got like 3 rows.
EDIT: They are also stretched horizontally, didn't notice immidiatly because the width of the container is almost the same as 3x(square + margin)

Comment: `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`  [Tut-tut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis/).  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added something like that now

Comment: @teuneboon (sigh) IMO, and for the sake of getting help, there are things that are SSCCEs and there are things that are *not* SSCCEs.  What you posted is in the latter group.  Please read the link very carefully.

Answer (score 2):

if all `JComponents` could have the same `HEIGHT` and `WEIGHT`, then look for `GridLayout`

in case that the `JComponent` couldn't same `WEIGHT`, then put each `"line"` to the separate `JPanel` (by using `BorderLayout` or `BoxLayout`) and use `GridLayout` for put these `JPanels` into `Container`